# Transporting a dog in the back of a pickup truck

Tags: dogs, travel

I'm finding it difficult to figure out the best way to transport my 65 lb. Labrador Retriever in the back of my pickup truck. There is no canopy on the truck. It's not ideal to have her up in the cab since its just a single cab truck and there isn't room when there is a passenger.

I've tried using her wire framed kennel, strapped in place so it doesn't slide around and so she is secured, but I find that she then has trouble keeping her footing when turning corners (the plastic mat/tray is too slippery).

I am not interested in just letting her be free in the back like I see some dogs, because I think its too risky for her to fall out, or be injured for the same reasons in slipping around in the bed of the truck.

I was considering getting a rubber horse mat to place in the wire framed kennel to help keep her stability if she isn't laying down.

I've also considered getting a smaller carrier of the firm plastic material so that her toes are more protected in the event she does slip (the wire kennel could possibly hurt her toes if snagged).

99% of my trips are never more than 30 minutes, unless we taking her camping where the trip might be 1 to 1.5 hours.

Safety and comfort are the things I am most interested in.

Please let me know what you do for your dog in similar situations.